# Please check my solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a field having $8$ elements and $a,b \in R$. If $a^{2} + ab + b^{2} = 0$, show that $a = b = 0$.
SOLUTION: Consider $a^{3}-b^{3}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{2}+ab+b^{2}\right)=\left(a-b\right)\left(0\right)=0$

so $a^{3}-b^{3}=0$

$\Rightarrow a^3=b^3$

$\Rightarrow a=b$

Then $a^{2} + ab + b^{2} = 0$

$\Rightarrow a^{2} + a\cdot a + a^{2} = 0$

$\Rightarrow 3a^{2} = 0$

$\Rightarrow a = 0$

$\Rightarrow b = a = 0$

Is my way correct? Is it allowed to write $a^{3}=b^{3}$ as $a=b$? Please help.

Comment: @Max $uv=0$ implies $u$ or $v$ is $0$ in any integral domain. In particular, $a^2=0$ in a field implies $a=0$.

Comment: @Max $a^9\neq a$ in general.

Comment: OP: the implication $a^3=b^3$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=b$ isn't true in just any field. You might want to include an argument as to why it holds in this one.

Comment: @Marc Bennet I will better remove the wrong comment then. (but can you explain why? note that i used $ card R=8$ here)

Comment: @Max Obviously $a^9=a$ isn't true in general. For example take a real number greater than $1$ for $a$. It doesn't hold in ${\Bbb F}_8$ either; if $k$ is a finite field the correct statement is $a^{|k|}=a$ for all $a\in k$. So here, we would have $a^8=a$.

Comment: no, $a^{|k^\times|}=1$ is true for all $a\in k^\times$ by Lagrange's theorem. Multiply this equation by $a$ and get $a^{|k|}=a$.

Comment: The non-zero elements of a finite field form an abelian group under multiplication. In a field with eight elements there are seven non-zero elements, which tells you that the group is cyclic of order $7$, since that is the only group available (Group Theory tells us that the only groups of prime order are the cyclic ones). All the non-zero elements satisfy $a^7=1$, and all the elements including zero satisfy $a^8=a$.

Comment: Then could please write the correct solution? I am having exams so I don't have enough time to think on this...Being a math student sorry to say like this.

Comment: As explained by Mark Bennet, it is crucial that the question is about a field of 8 elements. It is false for example in fields of 4 or 16 elements.

Comment: I've added some notes to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove that if $c^3=(ab^{-1})^3=1$ then $c=1$. Note that the multiplicative group of the finite field of order $8$ has order $7$, and the order of any element divides the order of the group.

What you have at the moment is simply a reformulation of the problem, and you aren't referring to any properties of the field itself. Since there are fields where $a^2+ab+b^2=0$ has non-trivial solutions ($\mathbb C$ for example) you need to find something about the particular field you are studying to justify your conclusion.

---

A standard kind of proof would run: if $c^7$=1 and $c^3=1$ then $1=(c^3)^5=c^{15}=(c^7)^2c=c$.

Therefore $a=b$ etc

Further note: This implicitly uses that we can find $p$ and $q$ with $3p+7q=1$. Here $p=5, q=-2$. There are standard methods in elementary number theory to find such $p$ and $q$ for any pair of co-prime integers.